# Get Image With file_get_contents it return Not Found Error

Tags: php, image, opencart, file-get-contents, file-put-contents

I have one Image on another server ([Image](http://www.lagrolla.com.au/image/data/m%20fr%20137%20group.jpg)).but when i get this image With `file_get_contents()` function it will **return**

> Not Found Error

and generate this [Image](http://development.kenzdesigns.com.au/image/catalog/lagrolla/m%20fr%20137%20group.jpg).

```
file_put_contents(destination_path, file_get_contents(another_server_path));
```

plz help me. if there are another way to get those image.

Comment: For me it is working fine. Maybe you don't have `allow_url_fopen` in PHP configuration set to true?

Comment: ya dear i set that `ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1);` in my page. but till not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this.

There is problem with URL Special character.then you have to decode some special character from url basename.

```
$imgfile = 'http://www.lagrolla.com.au/image/m fr 137 group.jpg';
$destinationPath = '/path/to/folder/';
$filename = basename($imgpath);
$imgpath = str_replace($filename,'',$imgpath).rawurldecode($filename);
copy($imgfile,$destination_path.$filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to download copy file from another server is using `curl`:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.lagrolla.com.au/image/data/m%20fr%20137%20group.jpg');
$destinationPath = '/path/to/folder/filenameWithNoSpaces.jpg';
$fp = fopen($destinationPath, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Note: It is bad practice to save images with spaces in file name, so you should save this file with proper name.

Comment: dear there no problem with file name, because file name set to returned content but it will return not found page so ..

Comment: Right, its only some note, and I know that's not an issue. What happened when you trying to download this file using `curl`?